# Filter results after using group-by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Type     Months     Year    Marks
 a        1          2018     64
 a        1          2017     69
 a        1          2016     69
 b        1          2018     78
 b        1          2017     71
 b        1          2016     91
 c        1          2018     58
 c        1          2017     65
 c        1          2016     83

 a        2          2018     58
 a        2          2017     65
 a        2          2016     83
 a        3          2018     58
 a        3          2017     65
 a        3          2016     83
```

I want to group by 'Type' , 'Months' , 'Year' and sum up the marks.

```
sumOfTypes = data.groupby(['Type','Months','Year'])['Marks'].sum()
```

The results looks like:

```
(a, 1, 2018)                  60
(a, 1, 2017)                  54
 .
 .
(c, 1, 2016)                  86           
(c, 2, 2018)                  89
```

However, I want the to filter the data to for Type 'a' and 'b' only.

Also, I want to vut (c, 2, 2018)  to be in different  dataframes columns so the result would look like:

df_grouped:

```
   Type     Months     Year    Marks    
    c         2        2018     89
```

My current code:

```
sumOfTypes = data.groupby(['Type','Months','Year'])['Marks'].sum()
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(sumOfTypes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `as_index=False` or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for return `DataFrame` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
sumOfTypes = data.groupby(['Type','Months','Year'], as_index=False)['Marks'].sum()
#alternative
#sumOfTypes = data.groupby(['Type','Months','Year'])['Marks'].sum().reset_index()

df = sumOfTypes[sumOfTypes['Type'].isin(['a','b'])]
```

Or filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `MultiIndex Series`, for select level use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
sumOfTypes = data.groupby(['Type','Months','Year'])['Marks'].sum()

s = sumOfTypes[sumOfTypes.index.get_level_values('Type').isin(['a','b'])]
```